# Why Tauri resourceDir() returns incorrect path

Tags: configuration, tauri

```bash
# my setting
npm create tauri-app@latest
```

```ini
# Cargo.toml

[package]
name = "tauri-app"
version = "0.0.0"
description = "A Tauri App"
authors = ["you"]
license = ""
repository = ""
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[build-dependencies]
tauri-build = { version = "1.2", features = [] }

[dependencies]
tauri = { version = "1.2", features = ["fs-all", "path-all"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"

[features]
# this feature is used for production builds or when `devPath` points to the filesystem
# DO NOT REMOVE!!
custom-protocol = ["tauri/custom-protocol"]
```

```
import { resourceDir } from "@tauri-apps/api/path";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          const resourceDirPath = await resourceDir();
          console.log(resourceDirPath);
        }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

expected : C:\Users\me\Desktop\study\tauri-app\src-tauri\target\debug\

result : \\?\C:\Users\me\Desktop\study\tauri-app\src-tauri\target\debug\

(added prefix 2 backslash + question mark + backslash)

Comment: have you enabled path?
`https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/path/` you have to update `tauri.conf.json` file